# Override a custom theme template for a specific node

Tags: 7, theming

I have a custom tpl file (node--product.tpl.php) for my product node types. I'm creating a special featured page (Also a product node) but I want to create a different layout for this one node. I created another tpl file (node--58.tpl.php) but it wont override my product template. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: enable devel themer , it should gives you the right override

Comment: There has to be a built in way to do this in drupal without requiring an entire module.

Comment: of course , but devel themer will gives you only the right override , then after you will disable it

Comment: Provide an answer with instructions on how to do this with devel. Thanks in advance.

Comment: be sure that the node ID is 58 , and clear also the cache , because node--58.tpl.php is the good override

Comment: I am 100% positive it is 58 and I already tried that override. Its still reading from my other template node--product.tpl.php

Comment: NM. It worked I guess i was impatient.